# training the area learning in project tango with other data sources

Tags: google-project-tango, object-recognition

Is it possible to train the area-learning module in a project tango device with other data than the one automatically input through the sensors?

I am asking because I want to teach the area algorithm a preexisting 3D model, thereby making object recognition possible. 
I am not asking for a highlevel ability to convert any 3D model to an ADF. If I have to generate several point clouds and color buffers myself based on the 3D model, that would also work.

I am also not asking to know about any Google secrets of the internal format of ADFs. Only to have some way to put data in there.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, there's no way of doing that through Tango public APIs. All pipeline, learning or relocalizing have to be done on device.